# Why do I get different results when I resize the dataset before uploading it

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, dataset

I am using the PyTorch framework to de the experiment. Normally I would use the code below to process the dataset before passing it to the neural network.

```
transforms.Resize(256), 
transforms.CenterCrop(224), 
transforms.ToTensor(), 
transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
```

But sometimes the dataset is too large, so I would use the `transforms.Resize(256)` to process the dataset before I upload it to the server. Then I only use the code below to process the dataset before passing it to the neural network.

```
transforms.CenterCrop(224), 
transforms.ToTensor(), 
transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
```

Theoretically, there two operations should be the same one, but normally I don't know why I would go different accuracy result.

Comment: The two operations would be same only if all images in the dataset are of spatial size (256, 256). If they are not, then resizing to 256 would give a different centre-crop compared to the original size centre-crop.

Also not sure what you mean by "dataset is too large". Are you talking about the number of samples in the dataset or the resolution of images?

Comment: I am sorry, I mean the capacity is too large. The dataset is 60GB and it only got 10MB if I resize them before I upload them to the server. But I still don’t understand. What makes it different? The only difference between this two operations is resizing the dataset before or after uploading them to the server.

Comment: What is the original resolution of images in your dataset? Suppose images are 512x512. When you resize to 256x256, the centre crop of 224x224 will be different compared to if you directly take a centre crop of 224x224 from the 512x512 image.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but that’s not how it works.For instance, all image resolution in dataset is 512 X 512.
First operation: upload them directly to server and use the code 
`transforms.Resize(256),transforms.CenterCrop(224), transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])`
to process them.

Comment: Second operation: resize all images to 256 before upload them to the server, then use the code
`transforms.CenterCrop(224), transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])`to process them. Because I already resize them to 256, so I remove the code `transforms.Resize(256)`.

So both operations are resize to 256, just if I resize them before upload to the server, the capacity would became smaller.

Comment: Should be same ideally. Did you check that both the resizing use the same interpolation method (like bicubic or bilinear)?

Comment: Yes, the interpolation method is consistent. I guess it has something to do with compression because there will have a certain degree of quality loss when saving the image after `transforms.Resize(256)`, and if I set quality to 100, the loss gap will be smaller, but it won't be exactly the same.